# What is the name of the Windows 8 start menu?

Tags: windows, windows-8

I'm trying to discuss it with my friends and I know whatever I call it will be the way they reference it probably forever.
Is it just Start Menu?
Metro Start Menu?
Modern Start Menu?

Comment: Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious Start Menu

Comment: Tablet Start Menu?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's the "Start screen".

According to the MSDN "Building Windows 8" blog article "[Designing the Start screen](https://web.archive.org/web/20151103041325/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/b8/archive/2011/10/04/designing-the-start-screen.aspx)" anyway. :)

And according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Start_menu#Start_screen):

> The **Start screen** is the successor of the Start menu. This feature is present in Windows Phone, Windows 8, and Windows Server 2012.

Comment: Thanks.  Two great references.  I should have went to Wikipedia to begin with.